# Error using Async/await and SqlDataReader with ExecuteReaderAsync in .NET Framework for a ASMX Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, sqldatareader

I am trying to write an asynchronise write to a database.  Everytime I call **ExecuteReaderAsync** I keep getting object not set to an instance.
Below is an excerpt from my code:

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var commandText = myCommand;
                await conn.OpenAsync();

                var command = conn.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = commandText;
                command.CommandTimeout = timeout;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TruckIds", truckIds);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        { 
                            Do Stuff
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The error I get is the following:

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT
>
> Process ID: 21128
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>
> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean
>   setImpersonationContext)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean
>   setImpersonationContext)    at
>   System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.b__18_0(Object
>   s)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Any thoughts or ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have is this method called? Do you await it all to the top? This typical happens when you do not await a Task.

Comment: Yes, I await all the methods, I am not unfamiliar with the async / await, however, I think the error lies in the fact that I am calling it in a web service.  Would converting the web service to a WCF service really solve the problem?

Comment: Please post the source code of your `*.asmx` / `*.asmx.cs` file because ASMX does not support `Task<T>`. I'm curious how you're doing it.

Comment: _write to a database_ - but you do `ExecuteReader`. Is it INSERT or SELECT sql-query?

Comment: The check `reader.HasRows` seems redundant to me. Looping `while (await reader.ReadAsync())` should be enough. Maybe it's important, because this way you are mixing sync and async calls.

Comment: This error means that the request completed while a call was still being awaited. You can set the `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` configuration key (http://vegetarianprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/12/understanding-synchronizationcontext-in.html) to prevent this error from crashing your process, but it won't solve the root issue.